# R language - Get top results from data set - Order results

Tags: r, many-to-many, time-series

I have this data in a flat file-

```
State Date HasASale
CA 2013-01-01 1
SC 2013-01-01 1
NY 2013-02-01 1
MN 2013-03-01 1
WA 2013-04-01 1
CA 2013-05-01 1
SC 2013-05-01 1
```

It is a many to many relation for state to date.

Which months have most sales? 
Which state has most sales?

I want to be able to plot the results.

I am using R to get this information. I am able to read the information-

```
hm <- read.table("states.data", header=T, sep="")
df <- data.frame(hm$Date,hm$States, hm$HasASale)
az <- with(df, zoo(hm.Freq, hm.Date))
df.TS <- aggregate(az, as.yearmon, sum)
df.sts <- aggregate(az, list(h=hm$States), sum)
```

This gives me the aggregates. How can I get the top 20 states by sales.
Or top 20 sale dates?

Comment: Please read some of the guidelines for SO: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results". Thanks!

Comment: Dump of your data (or at least sample) would be preferable. You can get it with `dput(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple solution with `by` and `with` should work even on your starting dataset.

```
statesBYsales <- c(with(df, by(HasASale, State , sum)))
```

Analogically with dates

```
datesBYsales <- c(with(df, by(HasASale, Date, sum)))
```

After you will get those vectors, simply sort the vector and print first 20 values.

```
sort(datesBYsales, decreasing = TRUE)[1:20]
```

Comment: Firstly you have to attach your data frame to use this. So `attach(df)`, then I assume that your dates are factors (default) and `HasASale` is equal to one, then use this command `unique(df[Date%in%as.factor(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-01-12"), "days")),1])`

Comment: Can you explain why you unnaccepted my answer? It answers your original question completely and you were accepted it before.

Comment: Sorry that was accidental.